# Sending Array of array in alamofire

Tags: swift, alamofire

I work for a swift project for medicine reminder and the application working in offline and online, so the user can save a lot of reminders, and once the internet is available I need to send the array of object to the API. I'm using Alamofire 4.4
and here is my code to get the parameters and put it in the array

```
var medArrTosendToServer =  [(_id:String, _timing:String)]()

    func getParameters() -> [[String: AnyObject]] {
    var result = [[String: AnyObject]]()

    for med in medArrTosendToServer {
        let medRes: [String: AnyObject] = [
            "device_id": DEVICE_ID as AnyObject,
            "userProfileID": userProfileID as AnyObject,
            "medName": med._medName as AnyObject,
            "timing": med._timing as AnyObject

        ]
        result.append(medRes)
    }
    print(result)
    return result
}
```

and in sned to server function

```
    func sendDataToServer() {

        let param  = getParameters()

        Alamofire.request(URL_POST_UserProfile, method: .post, parameters: param )

            .responseJSON

            { response in

                switch response.result {

                case .success( _):

                    if let JSON = response.result.value{

// here if success

                    }

                case .failure(let error):

                    print(error)

                   // self.stopAnimating()

                }

        }   

    }else{

        //self.stopAnimating()

    }

}
```

but I'm getting an error says "Extra argument 'method' in call". 
so if anyone has an idea to handle this case please share it with me

Thanks

Comment: Maybe you're just missing the appropriate _key_ for the value you append to the _result_ array. You can try with adding the key like
`result.append("yourKey": medRes)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As `Alamofire` `parameters` expects a type of `[String: Any]` you need to create an `URLRequest` and add your `Array` in body like this :

```
func uploadDataToServer(dataToUpload: [[String: Any]], completionHandler:@escaping (Bool) -> ()){

    let urlString            = "Your url string"
    guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else {
        return
    }
    var request        = URLRequest(url: url)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    do {
        request.httpBody   = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: dataToUpload)
    } catch let error {
        print(error)
    }


    Alamofire.request(request).responseJSON{ (response) in

        print("Success: \(response)")
        switch response.result{
        case .success:
            if let statusCode: Int = response.response?.statusCode {
                switch statusCode{
                case 200:
                    completionHandler(true)
                    break
                default:
                    completionHandler(false)
                    break
                }
                break
            }
        case .failure:
            completionHandler(false)
            break
        }
    }
}
```

Also `[String: Any]` is better option because it can store value of `Any-Type` but `AnyObject` will take only `Object-Type`. Also `[[String: AnyObject]]` is not `Array` of `Array`, it is `Array` of `Dictionaries`.